# Installation of OS in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am working on android emulator. I successfully upgraded the kernel of emulator. now I want to change the OS of emulator. I know we can select the appropriate APIs from the android SDK manager. But i want to install jelly beans manually or you can say i want to upgrade ICS to jelly beans in emulator.

Is there any way to do manually install source code of android 4.3 on emulator??

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the API the emulator uses and then you'll probably have to restart it. I can't imagine it would simply change Operating Systems. I just create a different AVD for each API I use and run them when I need them (with an API 18 Emulator always running).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Android SDK to compile Android 4.3 from source.  Choose the emulator as your build target.  For example, to create an engineering build (full debugging capability, largest output size) for the ARM emulator:

```
$ lunch aosp_arm-eng
```

Visit the official Android page on Building the System for full details:
http://source.android.com/source/building-running.html

After the build completes (it will probably take a few hours, at least the first time) you can use the files from the out/ subdirectory of the source tree to run in the emulator.  These include system.img, userdata.img, ramdisk.img, etc